# Why I don't receive notifications from my apps when I start my pc?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a few installed apps on my Windows 10 Pc and I have for example alarm clock, and nameday calendar. They sends me notifications about alarms and the next nameday that I follow.

However it works only if my PC is turned on at the specified time. I would like to still get those notifications even if my PC was turned of. Can I do it? Is that depends on the operating system or on my applications?

Comment: No, actually not looking for any software if my windows can't follow the missed "events/alarms/notifications"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However it works only if my pc is turned on at the specified time. I would like to get those notifications even my pc was turned of. Can I do it? Is that depends on the operating system or on my applications?

Very likely the application only.

For example, MS Outlook will show reminders after the event (and will continue until they are dismissed).

However, this is obviously controlled within the application and that is where the logic is.

If the application itself only fires an event as and when it occurs and ignores all past events, then it won't do anything with them after you turn the PC on.

Comment: I meant when I turn on my pc I would like to get notifications like this:
There was a notification while your pc was turned off, now you can check what you missed...